# Problemas na ordenação por mais de um critério

Tags: javascript

Em java temos a possibilidade de sobreescrever a função compareTo de uma classe e utilizar o sort() para ordenar um vetor de objetos. Gostaria de fazer o mesmo com JavaScript, já sei que poderia usar essa chamada de função sort(propriedade) mas não estou conseguindo adaptar a função abaixo no sort. Acredito que seja porque quero utilizar mais de um critério de ordenação.

Tenho um objeto do tipo relatório, com as propriedades abaixo:
Eu quero ordenar por qualis, e depois por ano.
Quando eu tento chamar a ordenação 2 vezes, ele re-ordena para o ano e ignora a ordenação por qualis.

```
var relatorio = {
        ano: '',
        sigla: '',
        veiculo: '',
        qualis: '',
        fator: '',
        titulo: '',
        autores: ''
    };
```

Chamada da função:

```
Relatorio.sort(ordenacaoDinamica());
```

Função que estou tentando:

```
function teste(){
        var propriedade = 'qualis';
        return function (a,b) {
            if (a[propriedade] < b[propriedade]){
                return -1;
            } 
            if (a[propriedade] > b[propriedade]){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                propriedade = 'ano';
                if (a[propriedade] > b[propriedade]){
                    return -1;
                } 
                if (a[propriedade] < b[propriedade]){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Essa propriedade `qualis` é numérica ou texto?

Comment: é texto, a ordenação está funcionando, porém ao tentar ordenar dentro de qualis iguais, dá errado... ele re-orderna todo o vetor e ignora a ordenação anterior

Comment: Mas se é texto usar `<` e `>` não vai ordenar como deve ser. Podes dar uma array de exemplo(?) com 4 ou 5 elementos para montarmos uma demo

Comment: Sugiro que faça como o Sergio disse e monte um exemplo com a ordenação que diz não funcionar, para que nós possamos ver, testar e responder.

Answer (score 1):

Parecido como a forma que você estava fazendo com os `if`, você pode verificar se o `qualis` é igual ao outro, caso ele seja você verifica o ano.

No javascript você pode aproveitar que o valor `0` é interpretado com false para fazer:

```
let ordenacao = comparacaoDoQualis || comparacaoDoAno;
```

Segue um exemplo da função para ordenar:

```js
let relatorio = [
    {'ano': '2020', 'qualis': 'B2'},
    {'ano': '2017', 'qualis': 'A2'},
    {'ano': '2017', 'qualis': 'B2'},
    {'ano': '2018', 'qualis': 'A3'},
    {'ano': '2017', 'qualis': 'A3'},
    {'ano': '2018', 'qualis': 'B1'},
    {'ano': '2015', 'qualis': 'B2'},
];


relatorio.sort((a, b) => {
   let qualis = (a.qualis == b.qualis) ? 0 : ((a.qualis > b.qualis) ? 1 : -1);
   let ano = (a.ano == b.ano) ? 0 : ((a.ano > b.ano) ? 1 : -1);

   //se o qualis for 0 ele retorna o valor da comparação do ano
   return qualis || ano;
});

console.log(relatorio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```js
const data = [
    { qualis: 'A1', ano: '2017' },
    { qualis: 'A1', ano: '2014' },
    { qualis: 'A2', ano: '2011' },
    { qualis: 'A3', ano: '2012' },
    { qualis: 'A6', ano: '2019' },
    { qualis: 'A9', ano: '2020' },
];

function sortData(data) {
  return data.slice().sort((o1, o2) => {
    const qualis = o1.qualis.localeCompare(o2.qualis);
    
    if (qualis !== 0) {
      return qualis;
    }
    
    const ano = o1.ano.localeCompare(o2.ano);
    
    return ano;
  });
}

const sortedData = sortData(data);

console.log(sortedData);
```